# Are all ergodic random processes (at least wide sense) stationary?

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, ergodic

If not, please provide a simple example of a non-stationary process that is ergodic (in mean and covariance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [answered a similar question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1169/235) over on dsp.SE. For the convenience of those too lazy to mosey on over there for a look, or too proud to stoop to reading what mere engineers might be writing, and also for the sake of completeness of stats.SE as a repository of questions and answers on statistics and related subjects, I am reproducing below a part of my answer on dsp.SE.

Can there be a random process that is *not* stationary but *is* ergodic? Well, **NO**, not if by ergodic we mean ergodic in every possible way one can think of: for example, if we measure the *fraction* of time during which a long segment of the sample path $x(t)$ has value at most $\alpha$, this is a good estimate of $P(X(t) \leq \alpha) = F_X(\alpha)$, the value of the (common) CDF $F_X$ of the $X(t)$'s at $\alpha$ if the process is assumed to be ergodic with respect to the distribution  functions.  **But**, we *can* have random processes that are *not* stationary but are nonetheless *mean*-ergodic and *autocovariance*-ergodic.  For example, consider the process
$\{X(t)\colon X(t)= \cos (t + \Theta), -\infty < t < \infty\}$
where $\Theta$ takes on four equally likely values $0, \pi/2, \pi$, and $3\pi/2$. 
Note that each $X(t)$ is a *discrete* random variable that, in general, takes on four equally likely values $\cos(t), \cos(t+\pi/2)=-\sin(t), \cos(t+\pi) = -\cos(t)$ and $\cos(t+3\pi/2)=\sin(t)$,  It is easy to see that in general $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ have different distributions, and so the process is not even first-order stationary. On the other hand, 
$$E[X(t)] = \frac 14\cos(t)+
\frac 14(-\sin(t)) + \frac 14(-\cos(t))+\frac 14 \sin(t)  = 0$$ for every $t$ while
\begin{align}
E[X(t)X(s)]&= \left.\left.\frac 14\right[\cos(t)\cos(s) +  (-\cos(t))(-\cos(s)) + \sin(t)\sin(s) + (-\sin(t))(-\sin(s))\right]\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 12\right[\cos(t)\cos(s) + \sin(t)\sin(s)\right]\\
&= \frac 12 \cos(t-s).
\end{align}
In short, the process has zero mean and its autocorrelation (and autocovariance) function depends only on the time difference $t-s$, and so the process *is* wide sense stationary. But it is not first-order stationary and so cannot be
stationary to higher orders either. Now, when the experiment is performed and the value of $\Theta$ is known, we get the sample function which clearly must be one of $\pm \cos(t)$ and $\pm \sin(t)$ which have DC value $0$ which equals $E[X(t)] 0$, and whose autocorrelation function is $\frac 12 \cos(\tau)$, same as $R_X(\tau)$, and so this process *is* mean-ergodic and autocorrelation-ergodic (autocovariance-ergodic too) even though it is not stationary at all. In closing, I remark that the process is  not ergodic with respect to the *distribution function*, that is, it cannot be said to be ergodic in all respects.

Comment: You have demonstrated that strict sense stationarity is not required for mean and covariance ergodicity by providing an example that is only wide sense stationary.  Is wide sense stationarity a requirement?  Are there non-WSS processes that are mean/covariance ergodic?  I wonder if there are cyclostationary processes that are mean/covariance ergodfic....

Comment: @rhz  If a process **does not have a constant mean,**  but is _nonetheless mean-ergodic,_ meaning that for almost all sample paths $x(t)$, the integral $$\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T x(t)\, \mathrm dt$$ converges to a limit as $T \to \infty$ and this _limit is the mean of the process,_ **which** of the different means of the random variables comprising the process is being converged to?

Comment: Yes, of course.  My bad.